# Azure SQL Server Firewall Rule add multiple IP address using PowerShell for database connectivity

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

How do i add multiple  `IP addresses` to `Azure SQL Server` using `PowerShell`
so that multiple adminstrator can connect to database from their machines using `SSMS`. It can be done via portal but we have closed that route and everything is done via `PowerShell`

I have this code but i think it does not fit our requirement.

```
 $ServerFirewallRule = New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -ServerName $ServerName `
    -FirewallRuleName "AllowedIPs" -StartIpAddress $StartIp -EndIpAddress $EndIp
```

for example

admin 1 ipaddress-1:  158.****

admin 2 ipaddress-2:  196.****

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following PowerShell that add the current client IP Address to the Azure SQL Firewall white list. Your administrators can run the PowerShell manually or they can schedule a Windows schedule task that can run the PowerShell when a computer starts.

```
$subscriptionName = 'Your Subscription'
$ipGetCommand = 'http://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address' 
$firewallRule = 'My-Home'
$serverName = "Your Server Name";
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$queryResult = $webclient.DownloadString($ipGetCommand)
$queryResult -match '\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b'
$currentPublicIp = $($matches[0])

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName



If ((Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName $serverName -RuleName $firewallRule) -eq $null) {
    New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName $serverName -RuleName $firewallRule -StartIpAddress $currentPublicIp -EndIpAddress $currentPublicIp
}
else {
    Set-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule -ServerName $serverName -RuleName $firewallRule -StartIpAddress $currentPublicIp -EndIpAddress $currentPublicIp
}
```

Comment: It's better to use [ipify.org](https://ipify.org)'s API - [https://api6.ipify.org?format=json](https://api6.ipify.org?format=json). It returns back a JSON with your IP